# Article in the question "do you like". With or without articles

Tags: articles, countability

Do you like hamburger or do you like a hamburger ? 
Do you like orange or do you like an orange ?
Which one of these above is correct ?

Do we have to use a / an/ the articles after "like" or not ?

Answer (score 1):

The use of an article depends on context:

- If asking about eating one now, use, "Would you like an orange?" with the article.
- If asking one's general preference, use, "Do you like oranges?" plural, *sans* article.

Since uncooked ground/chopped meat, AKA "hamburger", is uncountable, like water, but when used *with* the indefinite article, it changes meaning to (countable) cooked patties, the questions would be a bit different:

- If asking about eating a cooked patty now, use, "Would you like a hamburger?" with the article.
- If asking one's general preference for cooked ground meat patties, use, "Do you like hamburgers?" plural, *sans* article.
- If asking one's general preference for ground meat, use, "Do you like hamburger?" singular, *sans* article.

Sorry about any confusion engendered with countable vs. uncountable nouns. sigh

Answer (score 0):

*Do you like [food]* is a general question not, a specific one, so it is very unusual for the [food] to be singular. It is generally plural (*Do you like oranges?*) or uncountable (*Do you like fruit*). In neither case is an article normal.